# Convert dictionary with tuples as keys to JSON

Tags: python, json, tuples

I want to convert a dictionary to a JSON object, but my key is a tuple, hence I am getting an issue when I do that:

```
import json

d = {(300, 341): 4, (342, 426): 5}
json.dumps(d)
```

Error:

> TypeError: keys must be str, int, float, bool or None, not tuple

How can I solve this and access key elements if converted to JSON?

Comment: seems like you want defaultdict module i guess

Comment: Is it okay for you to cast the tuples to strings, for example?

Comment: @GhostOps What does defaultdict have to do with this?

Comment: I thought the keys can be in list using defaultdict, but anyway its upto the OP

Comment: @EricÁvila no I want it as tuple itself since I access want to access each tuple element from key

Comment: @mkrieger1 I get this error with that solution AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'

Comment: @mkrieger1 but the tuples get converted to strings there I dont want that

Comment: There's no other way. At least not without rearranging the structure of the data which we can't guess what would work for you.

Comment: `iteritems` is old (Python 2), now it's just `items`.

Comment: @shee are you using Python 2? that seems pretty important info. I guess it could be worth tagging it in the question?

Comment: @rv.kvetch No they are not, they were trying to copy code from another answer that was written for Python 2.

Answer (score 0):

As the error states, tuples cannot be keys of JSON objects and you need some kind of a workaround. Consider serializing the tuples to strings, but converting them back to tuples might be a bit tricky in such case.

```
d = {str((300, 341)): 4, str((342, 426)): 5}
json.dumps(d)
```

Other option is to change the way you store your data to something like this

```
d = [
  {'key1': 300, 'key2': 341, 'value': 4},
  {'key1': 342, 'key2': 426, 'value': 5}
]
```

obviously you may change "key1" and "key2" to something more meaningful.

edit:
As you mentioned you are working with ranges. How about this solution?

```py
def jsonify_data(d):
  jsonifable = {'%d:%d' % key: val for key, val in d.items()}
  json.dumps(jsonifable)

def dejsonify_data(jd):
  d = {}
  for key, val in jd.items():
    start, end = key.split(':')
    d[int(start), int(end)] = val
  return d
```

Answer (score -1):

You cannot convert a tuple to JSON directly, you would have to do it like this instead:

```py
dict = {
  300: 4, 
  341: 4,
  342: 5,
  426: 5
}
json.dumps(dict)
```

Comment: cannot do that since 300-341 is a range so i stored them in tuple to check range conditions

Comment: The answer is stated incorrectly: **tuples can be converted to JSON without issue**. The answer should specifically state that it applies to the case when tuples (or even lists) are used as keys in dictionaries.

Comment: Note also, that you're overriding the builtin type `dict` here. What happens when you do something like `dict()` in a following line?